# howto make a grid in a WP7 app bigger than the screen size?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have a problem with my WP7 app. i'm creating a screen where the user can make some input and then generate something.

but i can't fit the whole input into the screen size, so i would need a element which has a scroll bar or something and i can add so many elements as i which and then the user scrolls up and down. how to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ScrollViewer control that you can use. Put the grid in the ScrollViewer and you can then scroll around.

Answer (score 0):

encapsulate your content in a `<scrollviewer>` That should show a scrollable content.